# Getting result from browser just like Google OAuth

Tags: c#, oauth, google-oauth

When I use Google OAuth 2.0 in a client application for Authorization, it will open a browser window and ask me to login the google account, Then grant permissons, etc.
I'd like to know how could it work to transfer the result to the client application.
If I use C#, how could I design a similar login way for my client application to get the login result from the browser during the development.

Answer (score 0):

The initial authentication to google is a web URI.  There will be no way to not use a browser unless you intend to add it as a web browser component in your application.

Using C# I would go with the Google .Net client library.

Comment: I'd like to know **how did it works to return back the result(such as the secret) to the client**. As I need to develop a similar processes(call up a browser and back the result to the client) in my application.